# How to increase memory limit and number of cores that Rstudio uses on a cluster

Tags: cluster, r, slurm, rstudio

I launched `Rstudio` using `FastX` on `Rivanna` cluster (`CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)`):

https://arcs.virginia.edu/rivanna

The main goal for doing that was to significantly increase the speed of computations and memory limit, however, when I launched calculations, they are terribly slow, even slower than on my local machine. Besides, memory limit is very low too, so I ran into an issue:

```
> sce <- newSCESet(countData=UMI_count)
Error in asMethod(object) : 
Cholmod error 'out of memory' at file ../Core/cholmod_memory.c
```

Seems like I need to specify some additional settings to increase the number of cores and memory that Rstudio can use. How could I do that?